# My bill payment is due between the 12/6/2020 and 29/6/2020. Can i pay on either of those dates as well as the days between them?

Tags: contract-law

Like i said my bill is due between 12/6/2020 and 29/6/2020. Could i set up a direct debit payment paying it on the 12th or the 29th as well as the rest of the days in between them? I don't think you need images or links to answer this one. I've come to the conclusion that those two date are included in the window of payment but would just like to check with a profesional. Thanks!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://english.stackexchange.com

Comment: Its also completely dependent on jurisdiction and often the specific creditor in question - ask them what they would accept, as they are the authority on what they will and wont accept.  There might be a legal argument to make for one interpretation over another, but short of going to court over it theres little other way to force the other side to accept your interpretation - so ask them what theirs is.

Comment: @BlueDogRanch This is a legal question, not an English question. Interpretation of the terms of a contract is appropriate for law.se and is a field of study in the legal field.